# Jersey REST issue with consuming JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

i found myself in a situation where i need to get some data with POST on my server and do some simple stuff with it. But it keeps saying 415 Unsupported Media Type when i try to test it with www.hurl.it website.

This is my json that i am sending:

```
{
  "pictures": {
    "picture": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "10_aut_linen_male_less_student_work_yellow_n_cold.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "10_aut_linen_male_less_student_work_yellow_n_mild.png"
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "10_aut_linen_male_less_student_work_yellow_n_hot.png"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

this is the model class:

```
package com.models.sm7;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Sm7Pictures {
private Pictures pictures;
    public Pictures getPictures() {
        return pictures;
    }
    public void setPictures(Pictures pictures) {
        this.pictures = pictures;
    }


public class Pictures {
    private List<Picture> picture = new ArrayList<Picture>();
        public List<Picture> getPicture() {
            return picture;
        }
        public void setPicture(List<Picture> picture) {
            this.picture = picture;
        }

    }



public class Picture {
    private String id;
private String name;
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }


    }
}
```

This is my service class :

```
@Path("sm7Service")
public class Sm7Service {

    Sm7DAO sm7DAO = new Sm7DAO();


    @GET
    @Path("/testSm7")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String testSm (){

    return "Hello";}
    @POST
    @Path("/checkPictures")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getPictures(Sm7Pictures picture){

        System.out.println("pokrenuto");

    return "Hello";}

}
```

the DAO class is where i will do all my logic, but for testing purpouses i've just put text plain... I am really banging my head over this :S because it is simple but i can not get it to work. my bet is that it has something to do with the model class? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it, had to put `{}` inside `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` like this `@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})`.